just_audio + AirPlay[Flutter] - plays as a video (full screen saver) - how to fix?
I am using just_audio to play streaming audio in my flutter iOS app.
I will also use the dialog(flutter_to_airplay) to connect to devices that support AirPlay. When I switch the audio to mac - it works. But I also see a screen saver on my monitor (this is the splash screen of my mobile app). When I press "Esc" - the screensaver disappears but also the audio stops. It seems that my mac perceives it as a video broadcast. I saw this discussion, this is my code:
  final _player = AudioPlayer(
    handleInterruptions: false,
    androidApplyAudioAttributes: false,
    handleAudioSessionActivation: false,
  );
  
  await _player.setAudioSource(source);
  await _player.setAllowsExternalPlayback(false);

But it didn't help.
How can this be fixed?
